# Flink 1.5.1 on yarn

Tags: hadoop-yarn, apache-flink

I'm using flink 1.5.1 , that one cluster for one job

I submit a job to yarn wiht CLI, and then to cancel it ,there's sonething wrong that I can't understant

```
:~/flink-1.5.1/bin$ ./flink run -d -m yarn-cluster -ynm lz_test_alone1   -ytm 4096 -yjm 1024  -c Demo  /home/test/flink1.5_demo-1.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2018-08-10 15:05:28,390 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - Found Yarn properties file under /tmp/.yarn-properties-sloth.
2018-08-10 15:05:28,390 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - Found Yarn properties file under /tmp/.yarn-properties-sloth.
2018-08-10 15:05:28,937 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
2018-08-10 15:05:28,937 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
2018-08-10 15:05:29,324 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - Cluster specification: ClusterSpecification{masterMemoryMB=1024, taskManagerMemoryMB=4096, numberTaskManagers=1, slotsPerTaskManager=1}
2018-08-10 15:05:29,818 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory       - The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
2018-08-10 15:05:29,824 WARN  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - The configuration directory ('/home/flink-1.5.1/conf') contains both LOG4J and Logback configuration files. Please delete or rename one of them.
2018-08-10 15:05:31,087 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - Submitting application master application_1526888270443_0071
2018-08-10 15:05:31,121 INFO  org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl         - Submitted application application_1526888270443_0071
2018-08-10 15:05:31,121 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - Waiting for the cluster to be allocated
2018-08-10 15:05:31,126 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - Deploying cluster, current state ACCEPTED
2018-08-10 15:05:35,644 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - YARN application has been deployed successfully.
2018-08-10 15:05:35,644 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - The Flink YARN client has been started in detached mode. In order to stop Flink on YARN, use the following command or a YARN web interface to stop it:
yarn application -kill application_1526888270443_0071
Please also note that the temporary files of the YARN session in the home directory will not be removed.
Job has been submitted with JobID 4c4f9564adc94cd38d91d46660ade0d9

:~/flink-1.5.1/bin$ ./flink cancel 4c4f9564adc94cd38d91d46660ade0d9
2018-08-10 15:05:55,484 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - Found Yarn properties file under /tmp/.yarn-properties-sloth.
2018-08-10 15:05:55,484 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - Found Yarn properties file under /tmp/.yarn-properties-sloth.
Cancelling job 4c4f9564adc94cd38d91d46660ade0d9.
2018-08-10 15:05:55,837 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - YARN properties set default parallelism to 3
2018-08-10 15:05:55,837 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - YARN properties set default parallelism to 3
YARN properties set default parallelism to 3
2018-08-10 15:05:56,026 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
2018-08-10 15:05:56,026 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.cli.FlinkYarnSessionCli                 - No path for the flink jar passed. Using the location of class org.apache.flink.yarn.YarnClusterDescriptor to locate the jar
2018-08-10 15:05:56,116 INFO  org.apache.flink.yarn.AbstractYarnClusterDescriptor           - Found application JobManager host name 'cluster23.org' and port '57813' from supplied application id 'application_1526888270443_0067'
2018-08-10 15:05:56,707 WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.shortcircuit.DomainSocketFactory       - The short-circuit local reads feature cannot be used because libhadoop cannot be loaded.
```

when I use 'flink run' that return me the jobID and applicationId (application_1526888270443_0071);

thenI use 'flink cancel  ' and the log show another applicationId  (application_1526888270443_0067), so it goes wrong .

Is there any one can help me?

Answer (score 0):

```
./flink cancel
```

use on yarn job need -yid
this srcipt should be ：

```
./flink cancel  4c4f9564adc94cd38d91d46660ade0d9 -yid application_1526888270443_0071
```

this works